# Carrierwave. Processing only after the model has been saved (model.id is nil)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I need to process attachments that a representant a pdf file.
But my processing depends on the model wich does not exist at this point (not saved).

I need configure uploader that he started to work only after model was saved. Or something like that.

*rails 4.0.1, carrierwave 0.10.0*

**backup_uploader.rb**

```
class BackupUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include RenderAnywhere

  storage :dropbox
  process :render_check

  def store_dir
  end

  def filename
  end

  def extension_white_list
    ["pdf"]
  end

  def render_check
    # To render following pdf, i need fullfilled model
    # Especially model.id

    set_instance_variable("check", model)
    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(render('checks/check.pdf.erb'),
      wkhtmltopdf: Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf').to_s,
      zoom: 0.81,
      margin: { top: 18, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }
    )

    rendered_path = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{@check.id}rendered.pdf"

    File.open(rendered_file_path,  "w") { |file| file.write(pdf.force_encoding("UTF-8")) }

    Prawn::Document.merge(self.current_path, [self.full_cache_path, rendered_path ])

  end

  end
```

**chek.rb**

```
class Check < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  mount_uploader :backup, BackupUploader

end
```

**checks_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @check = current_project.checks.build(check_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      if @check.save
        format.html {}
        format.js {}
      else
        format.html {}
        format.js {}
      end
    end
  end
```

**UPDATE:**

I have a solution but I do not like it. I think that there is a better way.

**How it works now:**

**chek.rb**

```
class Check < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project

  mount_uploader :backup, BackupUploader
  skip_callback :save, :after, :store_backup! # <= Skip storing
end
```

**checks_controller.rb**

```
def create
    @check = current_project.checks.build(check_params)
    backup = @check.backup
    respond_to do |format|
      if @check.save
        StorageWorker.perform_async(@check.id, backup.file.try(:file)) #<= This job perform processing.
        format.html {}
        format.js {}
      else
        format.html {}
        format.js {}
      end
    end
  end
```

**backup_uploader.rb**

```
class BackupUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  storage :dropbox

  def store_dir
  end

  def filename
  end

  def extension_white_list
    ["pdf"]
  end


  end
```

**storage_worker.rb**

```
class StorageWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include RenderAnywhere
  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(check_id, tmp_file_path)
    @check = Check.find(check_id)
    set_instance_variable("check", @check) # Need for rendering check.pdf.erb. See RenderAnywhere gem.
    pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(render('checks/check.pdf.erb'),
      wkhtmltopdf: Rails.root.join('bin', 'wkhtmltopdf').to_s,
      zoom: 0.81,
      margin: { top: 18, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }
    )

    rendered_file_path = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{@check.id}rendered.pdf"
    result_pdf_path = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/#{@check.id}result.pdf"
    pdf_file_paths = [rendered_file_path, tmp_file_path ]

    File.open(rendered_file_path,  "w") { |file| file.write(pdf.force_encoding("UTF-8")) }

    if tmp_file_path.nil?
      result_pdf_path = rendered_file_path
    else
      Prawn::Document.merge(result_pdf_path, pdf_file_paths)
    end

    @check.backup = File.open(result_pdf_path, "r")
    @check.save
    @check.backup.store!


    File.delete(result_pdf_path)
  end

end
```

Comment: You generate a pdf, before attaching, and need a tempfile before "uploading" it, correct? Why not use `TempFile`, and let CarrierWave name the file correctly?

Comment: I have two pdf files. One of them attached by user, and other i generate. Thereafter i merge both files in one. Problem is rendering is depend on model.

Comment: I don't see any question here.

Comment: What is the relevance of the filename of the generated pdf? You merge it with the given one. Do you need to "keep" the added part?

Comment: File name does not matter. It can be changed. The original file is not needed. I need only resulted merged file.

Comment: ZerO, Question is how prevent processing before model was saved.

Comment: It's not clear (to me at least) why you need a saved model before processing.

Comment: jcm, Because data from the model and other objects related to the model are involved in the generation of pdf. This template **render('checks/check.pdf.erb')** is visualization of the model. For successful rendering **i need full data include ID**.